# Help solving one dimensional third order Euler-Lagrange condition

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action

I have the following Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L}(t, x, \dot{x}) = \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dot{x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} b(x, t)^2 \tag{1}
$$

I am interested in solving for the $f$ for which the action $$\int_{t_0}^{T} \mathcal{L} \:dt$$ is stationary. If I'm not mistaken, the Euler-Lagrange condition for stationary action works out as follows:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \dot{x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} b(x, t)^2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} b(x, t) \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} \tag{2}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \:\rightarrow\:\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} \right) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \dot{x} \tag{3}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} \right) = 0 \:\rightarrow\: \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} b(x, t)^2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} b(x, t) \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = 0 \tag{4}
$$

$$
\rightarrow \: \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} b(x, t) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = 0 \tag{5}
$$

Substituting $u = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$,

$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} b(x, t) + u \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = 0 \tag{6}
$$

The following is a viable solution for $u$

$$
u = e^{-2 \ln(b) + k_1}= e^{k_1} / b^2 \tag{7}
$$

Where $k_1$ is a constant of integration.

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here to solve for $f$. I'm not even sure if the solution for $u$ in equation $7$ is unique. I'm also not sure how boundary conditions might influence the functional form of $f$. What if I have the termination condition, for example, $f(x(T), T) = \max(x - K, 0)$? (Where $K$ is some constant.)

It also seems it should be possible to treat equations $5$ and $6$ as an ODE rather than a PDE, but I'm not sure how.

If the problem is too difficult as stated, I would still be interested in the simplifying case where $b(x, t)$ is not explicitly dependent upon time, for eg., replace $b(x, t)$ with $b(x) = a x(t)$ where $a$ is constant.

Comment: Hi. I really don't see how you get from $(6)$ to $(7)$?

Comment: Are you missing a term $\:\:\partial^2 f/\partial x\partial t\:\:$ in the rhs of equation (2)?

Comment: @Gert Sorry, I included a constant of integration that shouldn't have been there. Now removed, plus I made an edit to spell it out more clearly.

Comment: @Frobenius I don't think so. The Lagrangian results from $df - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$, where $df$ is Ito's Lemma and $dx$ is an Ito process.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: OK, it seems I am wrong.